# PHPickerViewController add video editing screen aka (UIImagePickerController.allowsEditing = true)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller, phpickerviewcontroller

I would like to edit/compress video after selection like it was in `UIImagePickerController` with `allowsEditing = true`.

Still the new `PHPickerViewController` doesn't have this property and `Apple` says that there is no such property anymore [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668622). But there are apps in App Store that pushing "allowsEditing controller" after selecting asset from `PHPickerViewController`

Here is my PHPickerViewController implementation:

```
func openImagePicker() {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
            configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .automatic
            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)

            // Set the delegate
            picker.delegate = self
            // Present the picker

            present(picker, animated: true)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            imagePicker?.photoGalleryAsscessRequest()
        }
    }

extension EditController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    @available(iOS 14, *)
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the app in App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated this issue but indeed  there is no support for like as you mention `allowsediting`.

For example related to your question preset values for video edits was depreciated to `UIImagePickerController.ImageURLExportPreset.compatible` but There is no support for automatic compression. The picker will always pass the original video/image and it is up to the app to do the necessary compressions or edits.
You can check this Apple Document:  [imageExportPreset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/2897484-imageexportpreset).

Apple specifically mentions that we should be using this new one instead of the older UIImagePickerViewController. If someone wonder more : [Meet the new Photos picker](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10652/)